# Orange3 summarizing data, grouping data values

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-cleaning, data, orange

Is there a simple way in orange3 (not writing a Python script) to summarize data and group similar data values?

For example, instead of plotting a scatter with lots of data points, I would like to plot just the average y value at every x value. In pandas, this is easily done with groupby().mean().

Is there a similar widget/feature I'm overlooking in orange?

Comment: You can transpose (widget) your data and then use aggregate columns widget. Take a look to pívot table also.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not that I know of.
You could try Feature Constructor and define custom ranges or simply create a column with mean, then plot it. But that is not so different from Python Script.

Comment: `Feature Constructor` seems to have now way to calculate a dynamic average [because there is no way to reference the total number of rows of incoming data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38231/orange3-is-it-possible-to-get-the-total-number-of-rows-for-a-given-column-from) . You might be tempted to hard code it, but if you were to attempt to add or process a subset of the data, this would undoubtedly break.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: If you don't mind your data being vertical instead of horizontal, you can use `Box Plot` to plot multiple means vs subgroups

(Use `Box Plot` to plot your 'y's with against you binned 'x' subgroups.)