# Orange: Is it possible to get the total number of rows for a given column from inside 'Feature Constructor'?

Tags: python, visualization, orange

I'm using the `Orange` gui and have been asked to generate basic plots where values relative to a "mean" or  "Percentile Rank" are colorized.

I looked in `Feature Constructor`, but as far as I could tell it lacks a way to calculate the total number of rows, or instances of incoming data.

I've looked elsewhere for widgets that might help and stumbled upon `Box Plot`, however, if one attaches a `Data Table` to the output of `Box Plot`, we can see that no new columns contain the values of the mean or standard deviation are generated.

**Is there some widget that has a function that can output these values, or the total number of rows selected / in the data set so that I can write my own function?**

Answer (score 1):

[Python Script widget](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/pythonscript.html) looks like it might fit your needs, where, according to the docs, a code like this should give you the number of rows in a data set:

```
n_rows = len(in_data)
```

Comment: Try this: https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/tutorial/data.html